# How to toggle an app in Hammerspoon?

Tags: keyboard, automation

I know how to launchOrFocus() e.g.:

```
hs.hotkey.bindSpec( { hyper , "b"},
  function()
    hs.application.launchOrFocus("Google Chrome")
  end
)
```

but how do I launchOrToggle() ?

I want to toggle it, meaning, return to previous app and then again to Chrome and repeat this loop when pressing hyper and b.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it helps...

```
toggleApp = function(appName, launch)
  launch = launch or false
  local app = hs.application.get(appName)
  if app then
      if app:isFrontmost() then
          app:hide()
      else
          app:activate()
      end
  else
      if launch then
          hs.application.launchOrFocus(appName)
      else
          hs.alert.show("App '" .. appName .. "' is not loaded!")
      end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"ctrl"}, "escape", function() toggleApp("wezterm") end)
```